# Asymptotic density of circle graphs

Tags: graph-theory

A graph is called a circle graph if it is the intersection graph of a chord diagram (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_graph for more information on the definition). Is there anything known about the asymptotic density of such graphs? Intuitively, I would expect that almost all graphs are not a circle graph, but I have found no reference on this.

Comment: Can you be more precise about your definition?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I added an additional reference to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we label the points around the circle as $P_1, P_2, \dots, P_{2n}$, the number of labeled chord diagrams we can draw is $(2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5)\dotsm(3)(1) = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$: just draw a chord from $P_1$ to one of the other $2n-1$ points, then take the next unused point and draw a chord to one of the other $2n-3$ unused points, and so on. We have $\frac{(2n)}{n!^2} = \binom{2n}{n} \le 4^n$, so $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!} \le \frac{4^n n!}{2^n} = 2^n n! \le 2^n n^n = 2^{n + n \log_2 n}$.

Meanwhile, the number of labeled graphs on $n$ vertices is $2^{\binom n2}$, so the number of isomorphism classes of $n$-vertex graphs is at most $2^{\binom n2}/n! \ge 2^{\binom n2 - n \log_2 n}$.

Since $\binom n2 - n \log_2n \gg n + n \log_2 n$, almost all $n$-vertex graphs are not isomorphic to any of the $n$-vertex circle graphs.